# Any conda or pip operation give SSL Error in windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have tried installing or updating new packages in my windows 10 system wherein I have installed Anaconda3 (2019 version).But everytime I get the same SSL error. I would have suspect it could be company firewall issue , if the I could have accessed that in Home wifi network. But everywhere I get the same error . 
While running COnda Search, I get this error :

```
conda search
Loading channels: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

And with Pip install I get this error :

```
pip install keras

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting keras
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/keras/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/keras/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/keras/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for keras
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I have OpenSSL installed from this location "https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html" and have the lib folder set in the PATH variable. But nothing it working . Please suggest .

Comment: Check your firewall - are you on a home computer, or a work network?

Comment: have you set the https_proxy in your system ?

Comment: I am using my laptop so sometime I will be on work network and sometimes on home network. As I understand, home network won't have any firewall restriction.

Comment: @prashantrana : I have not set anything explicitly. Also I am not sure where to unset it.

Answer (score 116):

I was able to solve the issue following [THIS](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273) instructions.
Basically:
* copy the following files from **CONDA_PATH\Library\bin** to **CONDA_PATH\DLLs**

```
libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*
```

Comment: Worked indeed. I don't understand why fresh Anaconda install needs this copy. I did not change anything in their recommended settings.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! I suddenly started to have the same issues. But it is now solved. I can finally install packages in my environments.

Comment: Copying just the .dll files worked for me.

Comment: I had to use the search function on Windows to find a copy of those files

Answer (score 30):

On Miniconda, Win11 Pro x64. Wanted to create a new env and `conda install pip` and got the same issue suddenly.

- **Update base**
  `conda update --all` in (base) first and then trying `conda install pip` or whatever you tried again.

  Didn't work
- **Install latest OpenSSL**

  Didn't work
- **Copy latest OpenSSL DLLs to \bin and \DLLs directory**

  Copy `libcrypto-3-x64.dll` + `libssl-3-x64.dll`

  from `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin`

  to `C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin`

  and to `C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\DLLs`

  Didn't work
- Copy existing dlls from \bin to \DLLs

  Copy `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`

  from `C:\Users\username\miniconda3\Library\bin`

  to `C:\Users\username\miniconda3\DLLs`

  Worked

Comment: Thank you. Had to go looking when encountering catch 22... you need openssl to pip install openssl :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
conda update conda
```

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

***Solutions to above issues:***

**1. Try using Anaconda powershell prompt as shown in below image:**

[image]

**2. via base environement**

a. `conda activate base`

b. `conda update --all`

Note:

a. Conda always create default environment as base. we can activate the base environment to upgrade the conda.

Comment: +1 ```conda update --all``` (then delete and recreate environment) fixed it for me. Thankfully no need for anything more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Use anaconda navigator to install openSSL module, much simpler way and then go for installing other packages through anaconda terminal. But navigator is usually hassle-free.

Why that solution?

"openSSL" is a module that helps the system connect securely with source that provides python modules for installation.

Hence usually when new environments are created this package isn't available by default. So as to install any package we need "openSSL", indirectly means to install "openSSL" through terminal we need "openSSL" pre-installed in that environment (a paradox). So above solution a little hassle-free.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with condasslerror and certificate error. I found two way to get rid of that sslerror.
One of them is recreate your environment with

```
conda create --name venv python
```

That provides to install pip ssl and certificate packages as default.

If you already have an env created with Conda, you should install Openssl with

```
conda install openssl
```

then, `conda install pip`

Have a great one.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it simply by adding C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin path to the variable environment path:

-Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables".

-Click on the "Edit the system environment variables" option.

-In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.

-Under "System Variables", scroll down and select the "Path" variable, then click on the "Edit" button.

-Click on the "New" button, then add C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin to the list of paths.

-Click on "OK" to close all windows.

-Restart your terminal or command prompt, and try running the pip or conda commands again.

Adding the path to your environment variable allows your system to locate the necessary files for executing Anaconda and its packages. So your libcrypto-1_1-x64.* and libssl-1_1-x64.* files are able to be read now. Don't forget to modify the path by your own one

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your conda is up-to-date: conda --version

If not, run: conda update conda

Temporarily set your     ssl_verify variable to     false, upgrade the requests package, and then set     ssl_verify back to     true using the following commands:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
conda update requests
conda config --set ssl_verify true
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
conda install openssl
```

Comment: That just gives me the same error: `CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to download and install packages.`

Answer (score 0):

Download openssl here https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/ and insta;; in the main folder

Comment: Please explain why downloading from elsewhere and installing is a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the conda commands with the Anaconda Prompt

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Such a simple fix.
Taken from: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273

> Current Behavior Environment: Windows 2016 Server Installer:
> https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe
>
> with the fresh installation neither conda nor pip are able to work
>
> **Steps to Reproduce** Start Anaconda Prompt conda search conda gives an error message: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is
> not available
>
> Environment Information conda version : 4.5.12
>
> Resolution I did a trace with Process Monitor.
> D:\Anaconda3\DLLs_ssl.pyd search for the OpenSSL DLLs but in the
> wrong/current location! As they are not found the search goes to
> C:\Windows\System32 where we have the same DLLs, installed by an other
> application, but with a different version. :-(
>
> The DLLs delivered by Anaconda3 are located here:
> D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
>
> **My workaround: I have copied the following files libcrypto-1_1-x64.* libssl-1_1-x64.* from D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.**
>
> And it works as a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it simply by adding `C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin` path to the variable environment path:

-Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables".

-Click on the "Edit the system environment variables" option.

-In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.

-Under "System Variables", scroll down and select the "Path" variable, then click on the "Edit" button.

-Click on the "New" button, then add C:\Users\username\anaconda3\Library\bin to the list of paths.

-Click on "OK" to close all windows.

-Restart your terminal or command prompt, and try running the pip or conda commands again.

Adding the path to your environment variable allows your system to locate the necessary files for executing Anaconda and its packages. So your libcrypto-1_1-x64.* and libssl-1_1-x64.* files are able to be read now.
Don't forget to modify the path by your own one

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I didn't have an environment activated. For some reason, conda deactivate didn't return me to the base environment as I was expecting.

```
conda activate base
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
conda install openssl
conda update --all
anaconda-navigator --reset
conda install -c conda-forge labeling
anaconda-navigator
```

#when running anaconda navigator, update program will be executed to upgrade navigator and its components.

#Once everything done, put the verify back to true.

```
conda config --set ssl_verify true
```