# SSL error while trying to install Selenium through Anaconda 3 or PIP Install

Tags: pip, ssl-certificate, conda

I am unable to install Selenium through Anaconda3 or "pip install". I have to work in my office network. Already I tried following below instructions but it did not work out:

[Any conda or pip operation give SSL Error in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185945/any-conda-or-pip-operation-give-ssl-error-in-windows-10)

Below is the error message:

```
 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443 ......

 CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

 Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by 

 SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

Please help.

Comment: Since this is your office network, then it is probably company security that causes this. Your IT department are the ones that you need to talk to. We cannot help, as it is impossible for us to know if you need to set a proxy, some whitelisting needs to be done or similar. Your IT department a) knows their own security measures b) knows the equipment used in the company c) is paid to make sure that you can do your work from an IT perspective